# How does exactly this DAC work?

Tags: dac

So here it is:

[image]

I don’t know how exactly this circuits works. I don’t understand how that feedback loop sets up an accurate know current source biasing, and what transistor is it trying to bias, Q4? For what?

With accurate current matching I presume it means that currents stay the same no matter what the voltage Vout is, but exactly what currents and why does this circuit need this? How does putting Vbias in one of the transistors in the pair differential helps this? I don’t understand.

Lets say I have code 10 as my input, so I presume d1 = 1 (or some other voltage) and d2 = 0. What happens next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This architecture is based upon a simple current steering dac.
Although, usually it allows for differential input
signal control words (\$d_{1}\$,\$d_{1N}\$,\$d_{2}\$,\$d_{2N}\$,...\$d_{k}\$,\$d_{kN}\$) and a differential load (\$R_{L}\$ on each leg).

*"I dont know how exactly this circuits works. I dont understand how that feedback loop sets up an accurate know current source biasing, and what transistor is it trying to bias, Q4? For what?"*

An ideal current steering dac will have perfect current sources that add (across a resistive load) to create a voltage output
proportional to switches turned on or off. So you would like close to ideal
current mirroring under all conditions. The current source on the left mirror leg provides
feedback and a high impedance cascode to help acheive this. It can usually
be set by some Rref and vref that will fix the current of the mirror source and
provide robustness against variations.  The loads of the mirror are each
of the current steering blocks. Forcing one to be fixed with vbias will
help create ideal loads for the mirror and improve matching (rather than
have the loads vary with differential inputs).

The switches \$d_{1}\$,\$d_{2}\$, to \$d_{k}\$ will simply steer current proportional to the
input codes and sum across the output \$R_L\$=50 \$ohm\$. So for example,
if you had \$d_{1}\$,\$d_{0}\$ = 1,0 you would get half \$I_{1}\$ plus a full \$I_{0}\$ or
\$Vout= \$(\$I_{1}*\frac{1}{2} + I_{0}\$*1)\$*50ohm\$.

You might have an easier time starting with understanding
a basic fully differential current steering dac.

edit* per request in comment, [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BRWinter18DAC.pdf) is a good tutorial from Behzad Razavi. Note he doesn't show much in the way of current mirror architectures, but you can look up robust current mirror design for that.

edit2* I built an lstpice simulation to help you further. It uses binary weighted current cells and nmos inputs. It should be fairly simple to translate to thermometer (X1 for each current cell weight). You can just flip upsidown and use PMOS to match book.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any good sources in this basic fully differential current steering dac? Cus i dont find anything usefull.

Comment: link added to post.

Comment: What values does I1 and I0 have? What is their expression? I dont think they can be equal, atleast have a difference of 2x from each other. So If d1 = 1, I1 =1/2 so if every bit is 0 i would get maximum output voltage (when i should get 0V)? How does all this translates to the DAC transfer function Dout(Din) = code * Vlsb?

Comment: Also how does the current from Q3 is the same as the corrent from Q4? They only share the same gate but their source voltage is different and so is VGS and with that the current value

Comment: If the gate voltage on Q3 is the same as it is on Q4, then the current sourced by Q3 will be identical to that sourced by Q4. This applies to all the FETs to the right of Q4.  And this relationship holds so long as the characteristics of all the FETs are identical.  If that's not the case, then the currents will be different, even with the same gate voltage.

Comment: @GotBlackOps. Q3 and Q4 have same S and G voltages, so same current. That is basic mirror (assuming load mirror does not vary too much). If a control switch is off all the current will flow to the load node via the  fixed switch. If a switch is on, half will flow to load and half through the switch.

Comment: @pat  So the currents I1=I2=... could also be called unit current sources because they are all the same? But if they are all the same the output voltage for codes d1,d0 = 1,0 and d1,d0 = 0,1 would be the same? Also, assuming that this DAC has a reference voltage of 1V what would be the value of the Ilsb current (which i presume here is I1=I2=...)?

Comment: In this case we assume they are the same (thermometer coded). They could also be weighted as binary or another scheme. I highly suggest to build this in a simulator like ltspice. Use a very simple current mirror (two transistors) to understand the mechanisms.

Comment: Added simulation example in ltspice.

Answer (score 1):

When V(Rref) = Vref then I4 is known from Vref/Rref=I4 since the comparator nulls the input error with negative feedback using the 1st FET on the comparator as an inverter to the non-inverting feedback input for NFB.

This is common practice. The 2nd FET below it is a common gate config. and thus non-inverting, thus overall it is negative feedback (NFB).